# SQLite database insert is somehow vanishing?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-alertdialog

I'm having a very strange issue on my Android app wherein when I am inserting a value to a DB table, the first entry is disappearing somehow. However, any subsequent entries are appearing fine.

To be a little more specific, part of my application allows users to create a simple log where they enter some text and when they save it, it shows up on a list of log entries. However, when I try to insert the very first entry to an empty table, that entry is not being displayed, nor does the database indicate there is any data when I query for a count.

Interestingly enough, when I look at the return of the database insert call (SQLiteDatabase.insert()) I see a valid row number returned. In fact, when I look at any log entry I've saved to the database, the row number is correctly incrementing. As per the docs, my understanding is that if a non-negative number is returned, the insert was successful.

Here is the code that takes the result of the EditText from my AlertDialog, creates a new log entry, and calls the insert method:

```
newPainLogEntryDialog.setPositiveButton("Save",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                //make new pain log entry
                                PainLog painLog = new PainLog();
                                painLog.setPainEntry(input.getText().toString());
                                painLog.setPainDateTime(Calendar.getInstance());

                                Database.init(PainLogTab.this.getActivity());
                                Database.createPainLog(painLog);
                                updatePainLogList();

                                //display success to user
                                Toast.makeText(PainLogTab.this.getActivity(),
                                        "Log entry saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
```

The code for Database.createPainLog():

```
public static long createPainLog(PainLog painLog) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COLUMN_PAINLOG_ENTRY, painLog.getPainEntry());
        cv.put(COLUMN_PAINLOG_DATETIME, painLog.getPainDateTimeString());

        return getDatabase().insert(PAINLOG_TABLE, null, cv);
    }
```

And the last call before the Toast message is updatePainLogList(), which gets all the DB entries:

```
public void updatePainLogList(){
        Database.init(PainLogTab.this.getActivity());
        final List<PainLog> painLogs = Database.getAllPainLogs();
        painLogListAdapter.setPainLogs(painLogs);
        Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "number of painLogs found: " + painLogs.size());

        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // reload content
                PainLogTab.this.painLogListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                if(painLogs.size() > 0){
                    getView().findViewById(android.R.id.empty).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }else{
                    getView().findViewById(android.R.id.empty).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

And for completion sake, the body of the getAll() and its accompanying method getCursor():

```
public static Cursor getPainLogCursor() {
        String[] columns = new String[] {
                COLUMN_PAINLOG_ID,
                COLUMN_PAINLOG_ENTRY,
                COLUMN_PAINLOG_DATETIME
        };

        return getDatabase().query(PAINLOG_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null,
                null);
    }

    public static List<PainLog> getAllPainLogs() {
        List<PainLog> painLogs = new ArrayList<PainLog>();
        Cursor cursor = Database.getPainLogCursor();
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                PainLog painLog = new PainLog();
                painLog.setId(cursor.getInt(IDX_PAINLOG_ID));
                painLog.setPainEntry(cursor.getString(IDX_PAINLOG_ENTRY));
                painLog.setPainDateTime(cursor.getString(IDX_PAINLOG_DATETIME));

                painLogs.add(painLog);
            }
        }
        cursor.close();
        return painLogs;
    }
```

Now with some code I can explain what debugging steps I have taken thus far. As mentioned above, when I look at the return of the DB insert, I get a positive, non-zero number. However, when I try to print the number of logs in the immediately following update method (no deletes or anything get called en route), it displays 0, and indeed if I follow the Cursor I find that it never enters the loop which adds logs to the list which is displayed, also indicating it is not picking up the entry.

I have tried to set the DB insert in a transaction so that I can manually commit, but this does not help either. What makes this more interesting to me is that I have similar functionality elsewhere in my app where I save user preferences and display them in a list, and this does not suffer from the same problem...I have compared against this code and couldn't find any differences that would cause it.

To sum it up, my question is two-fold: why is only my first insert on an empty table showing up as not there, while all following ones are fine?; why am I getting a valid return from the database insert and yet immediately following the insert when I query for that data it is missing?

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
>
>     while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
> ```

This skips the first row in cursor. `moveToFirst()` moves to the first row and `moveToNext()` moves to the next one, skipping the first one.

You can replace this with just `while (cursor.moveToNext())`. When you get your cursor from a query, it is placed at index -1 first i.e. at the row before the first one.

Comment: Brilliant, can't believe I glossed over that. Thank you very much!

Answer (score -1):

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
```

This would be the best solution for it....